# VGPR usage and gl_FragColor vs. gl_FragData[n]

Tags: opengl, glsl

GPU Vendors recommend reducing the number of used VGPR (Vector General Purpose Registers) in a shader, because they are limited in amount and excessive use reduces GPU occupancy. So i compiled a simple fragment shader that emits white, and checked VGPR usage with the Radeon GPU Analyzer (RGA)

```
void main(void)
{
  gl_FragColor = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
```

To my surprise, it emitted a rather large shader

```
1 |   1 | ^                         | label_basic_block_1: v_mov_b32 v0, 0
2 |   2 | :^                        | v_mov_b32 v1, 1.0
3 |   3 | v:^                       | v_cvt_pkrtz_f16_f32 v2, v0, v0
4 |   4 | vv:^                      | v_cvt_pkrtz_f16_f32 v3, v0, v1
5 |   4 | ::vv                      | exp mrt7, v2, v2, v3, v3
6 |   3 | v:   ^                    | v_cvt_pkrtz_f16_f32 v5, v0, v0
7 |   4 | vv   :^                   | v_cvt_pkrtz_f16_f32 v6, v0, v1
8 |   4 | ::   vv                   | exp mrt6, v5, v5, v6, v6
9 |   3 | v:      ^                 | v_cvt_pkrtz_f16_f32 v8, v0, v0
10 |   4 | vv      :^                | v_cvt_pkrtz_f16_f32 v9, v0, v1
11 |   4 | ::      vv                | exp mrt5, v8, v8, v9, v9
12 |   3 | v:         ^              | v_cvt_pkrtz_f16_f32 v11, v0, v0
13 |   4 | vv         :^             | v_cvt_pkrtz_f16_f32 v12, v0, v1
14 |   4 | ::         vv             | exp mrt4, v11, v11, v12, v12
15 |   3 | v:            ^           | v_cvt_pkrtz_f16_f32 v14, v0, v0
16 |   4 | vv            :^          | v_cvt_pkrtz_f16_f32 v15, v0, v1
17 |   4 | ::            vv          | exp mrt3, v14, v14, v15, v15
18 |   3 | v:               ^        | v_cvt_pkrtz_f16_f32 v17, v0, v0
19 |   4 | vv               :^       | v_cvt_pkrtz_f16_f32 v18, v0, v1
20 |   4 | ::               vv       | exp mrt2, v17, v17, v18, v18
21 |   3 | v:                  ^     | v_cvt_pkrtz_f16_f32 v20, v0, v0
22 |   4 | vv                  :^    | v_cvt_pkrtz_f16_f32 v21, v0, v1
23 |   4 | ::                  vv    | exp mrt1, v20, v20, v21, v21
24 |   3 | v:                     ^  | v_cvt_pkrtz_f16_f32 v23, v0, v0
25 |   4 | vv                     :^ | v_cvt_pkrtz_f16_f32 v24, v0, v1
26 |   2 |                        vv | exp mrt0, v23, v23, v24, v24
27 |   0 |                           | s_endpgm 
Maximum # VGPR used   4, # VGPR allocated:  25
```

A closer look shows 'exp mrt0', 'exp mrt1' ... so clearly all eight available MRT tragets are written to. So i changed the shader a bit

```
void main(void)
{
  gl_FragData[0] = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
```

and the register allocation drops from **25 to 3** (!), the instruction count drops from **27 to 6**

```
1 |   1 | ^   | label_basic_block_1: v_mov_b32 v0, 0
2 |   2 | :^  | v_mov_b32 v1, 1.0
3 |   3 | v:^ | v_cvt_pkrtz_f16_f32 v2, v0, v0
4 |   3 | xv: | v_cvt_pkrtz_f16_f32 v0, v0, v1
5 |   2 | v v | exp mrt0, v2, v2, v0, v0
6 |   0 |     | s_endpgm 

Maximum # VGPR used   3, # VGPR allocated:   3
```

I am a bit puzzled now. I do not need MRT in this case, but anyways,

1. Why does writing to 7 MRT (mrt1..mrt7) use no less than 22 VGPR? Why cant we write from one register?
2. Just for interest, is this MRT writing done in parallel or we really spend more than 20 instructions for this?
3. If i write only to gl_FragData[0] / MRT0, does the shader execution speed benefit from reduced VGPR usage? If not in this case, would it benefit in cases where VGPR usage drops from e.g. 40 allocated to 18 allocated VGPR?

(Yes, I know that gl_FragDataXY are deprecated in the latest GLSL versions, but I still want to write code that can run on older cards.)

Comment: Which glsl version are you targeting? `gl_FragColor` and `gl_FragData` are both deprecated since GLSL 140 (around 2010).

Comment: Oh, excuse me, i forgot to mention "(Yes, I know that gl_FragDataXY are deprecated in the latest GLSL versions, but I still want to write code that can run on older cards.)"

Comment: My comment was maybe not very clear: 1) Unless you specify which OpenGL/GLSL version you are targeting, I don't see how the question could be answered. 2) "in the latest" is not really correct. We are now at version 460. The two variables you refer to are only valid in 110, 120 and 130.

Comment: Ok, so let it be version #120. Does the amount of VGPR used affect performance in these shaders?

Comment: Indeed, i changed the shader to write to 'out' and the behaviour is similar to gl_fragData[0].

This still leaves the question, does the amount of VGPR used affect performance in shaders using gl_FragColor?

Comment: That's the expected behaviour. `gl_FragColor` was introduces before multiple rendertargets were even possible. It was replaced in 130 with `gl_FragData` to solve that, but wasn't removed. It acts exactly as if you would write to all attachments. Unfortunately, I can't tell you how an answer to your questions.

Comment: Ok, please BDL and everyone out there forget for a second about the gl_FragColor and deprecation. It is not relevant here.


**The question is still the same: even if i _want_ to write to all available MRT, will this take more than 20 instructions and VGPR registers and thus massively reduce occupancy on GPUs?**

Answer (score 0):

> Why does writing to 7 MRT (mrt1..mrt7) use no less than 22 VGPR? Why cant we write from one register?

There is a distinction between "can't" and "doesn't" that you're not taking into account. The fact is that it's 2017: `gl_FragColor` is a pre-defined output that has been removed from GLSL for nearly a decade. AMD has zero reason to optimize the usage of this value.

So while it probably could do better, the compiler *doesn't* do better.

> If i write only to gl_FragData[0] / MRT0, does the shader execution speed benefit from reduced VGPR usage?

Optimization is not that simple. There's no way to know for certain, particularly in a real-world shader where the additional VGPRs used by the write to `gl_FragColor` might not matter, since it could reuse VGPRs allocated by other code allocated.

Comment: a) Regarding the deprecated gl_FragColor,  **please** either ignore it or replace it with _i want to write to all MRT_

b) Of course there are ways to know, either measure execution time(i failed so far on that) or ask people with experience (i apparently failed on that, too).

Comment: @Heiner: "*please either ignore it or replace it with i want to write to all MRT*" Then replace your code that uses it with code that writes to all attachments. Show us what that compiles to. If you don't want `gl_FragColor` discussed, don't use it as an example.